# PyQGIS loop of GRASS processing

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis

I have many nc files and for each one I would like to create a tif file with the average of the bands using `r.series` of grass processing in QGIS.
I wrote the code below but it doesn't work but no tif file is created and it gives me no error messages.

Using the processing tool, with one file it works.

```
import glob, os
path="C:/Users/Daniele/Documents/"
os.chdir(path)
for file in glob.glob("*.nc"):
        input_layer = (path+file)
        output_layer = input_layer.replace(".nc",".tif")  
    
    param = { '-n' : False, 
                'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META' : '',
                'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT' : '',
                'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER' : 0,
            'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER' : None,
            'input' : input_layer,
            'method' : [0],
            'output' : output_layer,
            'quantile' : '',
            #'range' : [nan,nan],
            'weights' : '' 
            } 

    processing.runAndLoadResults('grass7:r.series', param)
    ###########r.series average of bands of file nc

    ####### Reload your output layer ########

    #output_layer = QgsRasterLayer(path, file_tif,'ogr')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below is working when I try it (with tif files as inputs). I ran the tool manually in QGIS then used the command from History (Ctrl+Alt+H) and changed your code from `input_layer = (path+file)` to `input_layer = os.path.join(path, file)`

```
import glob, os
path="/home/bera/Desktop/tempgis/dems"
os.chdir(path)

for file in glob.glob("*.nc"):
    input_layer = os.path.join(path,file)
    output_layer = input_layer.replace(".nc","_output.tif")
    
    params = {'input':input_layer,'-n':False,
        'method':[0],'quantile':'','weights':'',
        'output':output_layer,'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,
        'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':0,'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'',
        'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':''}
        
    processing.runAndLoadResults("grass7:r.series", params)
```

Comment: for every nc file "2020-12-29T14:45:17     CRITICAL    ERRORE: Mappa raster non trovata
2020-12-29T14:45:17     INFO    C:\Users\Daniele\Documents\nc>r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputa58c73310aa14886adb6bc8316d7bec5" output="C:\Users\Daniele\Documents\nc\2020-11-01_2020-11-30_output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite"

Comment: @ BRERA Now i understand, nc files need to be uploaded to qgis before running python code. Thank you

Comment: By upload you mean add them to QGIS as layers?

Comment: yes, I noticed that the same thing happens when using the processing tools